# Can't inject Application context in abstract class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have in my AppModule following notation:

```
@Provides
@ApplicationContext
fun provideAppContext(app: Application): Context = app
```

and I want to use it in abstract class

```
@Inject
@ApplicationContext
lateinit var mContext: Context
```

But when I try to use the context (for call ressources.getString(..)), I get following error:

```
lateinit property mContext has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

for abstract class u cannot able to call the constructor.So better to use child class.